# Here map javascript api for Angular App, memory leak happen for open the here map page

Tags: here-api

when every time open here map page:

```
this.router.navigate(['/car-section/here-map'],  {replaceUrl: false});
```

html here map page code:

```
<div #map class="map-container">
```

Here Map Component:

```
export class HereMapComponent implements OnInit {

  private platform: any;
  private mapHere:any;

........

@ViewChild("map", {static: true}) public mapElement: ElementRef;

  constructor() {
    this.platform = new H.service.Platform({
      'apikey': API_Key
    });

   }

......


 public ngAfterViewInit() {

    setTimeout(() => {

      let defaultLayers = this.platform.createDefaultLayers();
      this.mapHere = new H.Map(
          this.mapElement.nativeElement,
          defaultLayers.vector.normal.map, //3.1
          // defaultLayers.normal.map,  //3.0
          {
              zoom: 16,
              center: this.center,
              pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
          }
      );
    }, 300);
  }
```

get memory leak, each time get two memory heaps leak :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOvJ0.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not surprising, given the fact that the Angular component lifecycle is destroyed when you navigate away from the view, and (re)created when you navigate to the view, while the HERE map objects reside on the global *H* object.

I think your Angular component should interface with *OnDestroy* and therefore implements the *ngOnDestroy* method. In that method, one should *dispose* the objects and handlers that have been *"imposed"* to the map.
Typically, we need to dispose event handlers, then map objects, then the map itself.
See for example the *dispose* method on **[H.Map API Reference](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/api_reference/H.Map.html#dispose)**.